# Calculating the average / MEAN of an attribute field in a QGIS model

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, qgis-processing

I need to know how to calculate the average / mean of an attribute field in my point shape file. Is this possible to do with the field calculator? I just found the options min or max but not mean. The result should be written in a new attribute field for further data processing. I would like to do this within a model.

Comment: see this plugin http://hub.qgis.org/projects/statist/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pretty late answer but you can do this in the Model Builder, a simple example is shown below:

[image: Processing modeler]

With your vector point layer already added, you can access the *Field Calculator*:

[image: Field Calculator]

In the **Formula** textbox, you can add your little equation to calculate the percentage. Depending on the column names of the attributes, you can use something like this:

```
("Altitude_Column" / Some_Total_Value) * 100
```

Answer (score 3):

You could get statistics on that field (Vector > Analysis Tools > Basic statistics) which will *tell* you the mean, and then create a new attribute and use Field Calculator to fill every record with that value.

Comment: But I wanted to do with the modeler.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by modeler? I'm familiar with ModelBuilder in ArcGIS, but the only QGIS equivalent I see right off is Sextante, and I don't know much about it. A Field Calculator works with *individual* records. By itself, it can't do a calculation involving *all* records like mean of a column. The min/max functions you found would compare fields in a record, not one field of all records.

Comment: Yes I'm using the sextante (now its called processing) model builder. I have a column with altiude values (70-132 m). I want to get a column with the relative values (percentaged).

Comment: @Pimpel Unfortunately I don't know enough about the QGIs modeler to work this one out just yet. I have edited your question to hopefully bring it to the attention of someone who may.