# How to get the average of a column?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

So I have a shapefile with 160k elements.
It is in UTM and I calculated the area (should be meters, right?).
What I need now is the average size of each of my polygons. 
Meaning, summing up a column and then divide this number by 160k.

Is there a straight forward way?

If there is no straight forward way, I'd rather do in Python than copying my attribute table to Excel and do it there.

Comment: Does this answer help? http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/110848/43

Comment: @RichardMorgan yes it does. 
Since my projection is UTM my results should be in meters, right?

Comment: The units better be in meters!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a direct way in QGIS: In the main menu you have to click on 'Vector' [My QGis is in spanish, but look for something like that ;)] in that menu you go to 'Analysis Tools' and click on 'Basic Statics', another window will open and there are two combo boxes and a list box; in the first combo you have to choose the shape you want to use for calculation and in the second one you choose the field you need (in your case should be 'Area' or something like that); then you click 'OK' and a list of many statics (wich includes 'Average') will be displayed on the list box. With [Ctrl + C] you can copy the statics on word, excel, etc.
Let me know if is that you wanted it!!!

Comment: yep. Just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

QGIS (version 2.16 and up) expressions now support aggregate functions, such as

```
mean(ATTRIBUTENAME)
```

They can be used in field calculator, labeling, and many other places ...

[image]