# Finding and using mean and standard deviation value in field calculator

Tags: qgis, field-calculator

I am creating a field for a z-score of a particular attribute. This requires calculating the mean and the standard deviation for the attribute across all features. I've been using the statistics window to get the mean and standard deviation, copying them into a field, and then doing the calculations in a third field, but I feel like that's not very efficient. I can't find a way to calculate the mean using the field calculator and my scripting skills are pretty weak.

Comment: check out http://hub.qgis.org/projects/statist/  & http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/99891/calculating-the-average-mean-of-an-attribute-field-in-a-qgis-model

Comment: The tip on using the modeler is helpful, but I can't figure out how to take the mean value from the basic statistics algorithm and use it elsewhere in the model. Is it possible to simply create a variable with the modeler that I can use in a formula?

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/143544/how-to-summarize-a-column-in-qgis-field-calculator   they say there you cant sum a field in qgis field calculator :/

Comment: @ed.hank - [Yeah...that was a long time ago](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/143700/25814) ;)

Comment: @joseph always good to have updated info!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the **Field Calculator**, you can use the following *Aggregate* functions:

- Mean

  ```
  mean( "fieldName" )
  ```
- Standard deviation

  ```
  stdev( "fieldName" )
  ```

---

*Tested on QGIS 2.18*

Comment: Hey, that's good to know about! Thanks for the updated answer on this.

Answer (score -1):

Zonal statistics plugin could be used.

https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_zonal_statistics.html